# Adding data in a csv file via powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, addition

Im looking for a way to be able to add all the values in a csv file via powerhsell. For example I have a column called 'someData' in file called outPut.csv. How would I be able to enumerate through all the entries in the column called 'someData' and spit out the result? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the sum (among other aggregate values), use the `measure-object` commandlet

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\infile.csv | measure-object -Property MyProp -Sum | select-object sum | fl
```

Comment: Thats is exactly what in after so thank you! I may need help with some other bits but this is a very good start!

Comment: Hi, Im unable to store the value correctly to use later on so if I try  '   $result = Import-Csv -Path c:\i.......    ' the value does not get stored and as a result so I cab do any extra arithmetics on $result I get errors?

Comment: No sorry completely new to powershell, could you possibly send the whole syntax? And I recon we are there!

Comment: Sorry that seems to still spit out something unusable like this "SUM --- value" so I cant actually store it as a variable.

Comment: `get-process | export-csv "procs.txt" ; $res = import-csv .\procs.txt | measure-object -Property CPU -Sum ; $res.sum ` gives 120.8975 on my machine

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\path\to\output.csv | Select-Object -Property someData;
```

or short-hand would be:

```
ipcsv c:\path\to\output.csv | select someData;
```

or even shorter:

```
(ipcsv c:\path\to\output.csv).someData;
```

**NOTE**: The last example requires PowerShell version 3.0 or later.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for swift response however that only returns the values in the column back onto the screen. I want to be able to add all the values for later use. Another words if column 'someData' has 3 rows with values 1,2,3 I want to be able to add these up and end up with a single result. Thanks :o)